# How to ssh into wsl running in virutalbox from linux host

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As the title suggests I have a windows 10 vm running in virtualbox on my host linux machine (Manjaro if it matters) and inside of my windows 10 vm I am running wsl 1 with a ubuntu 20.04 distro (This is done for IT security compliance).

I want to be able to communicate with wsl from my host linux machine so that I can execute command's via ssh since the vm has vpn access to my work's network that I don't on my host machine.

I've seen similar questions like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1123552/how-to-ssh-into-wsl) that details how to ssh into wsl, and I've found information about [how to ssh into virtualbox guest os's](https://medium.com/nycdev/how-to-ssh-from-a-host-to-a-guest-vm-on-your-local-machine-6cb4c91acc2e) but neither seems to really tie things together given the context of my problem.