# SSH to Ubuntu using Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, bash, ssh

Like many others, I've been excited to use bash on Windows 10.  I was able to get it installed fine.  However, I'm having trouble SSH into instances.  I've followed another post [here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1111591/how-can-i-ssh-into-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10?newreg=1ae6f839c3b545ed8852a5acdbb5d3fa).  But am not able to get it to work.  Do I need to specify something other than this type of command:

```
ssh -i /mnt/c/Users/uname/Desktop/key.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I get this error:

```
 Warning: Identity file key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

I have double-checked and that path to my key.pem is correct.

Comment: make sure you can login using a password to make sure the ssh-server is running properly. when succeeded; try logging in with putty, but use your key this time and post some screenshots of results getting there.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little simplistic but have you tried a program called Putty?

It seems to be a little better than inbuilt windows ssh

Comment: yes, have used Putty many times.  The reason I like linux is the ability to shell script, and having scp in that code is very important

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -i /mnt/c/Users/uname/Desktop/key.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

When I understand right you are trying to connect from bash on Ubuntu on windows to your amazon ubuntu server.

1. I am not using putty with pem files but the standard way to provide login without password is an rsa key (see at [digitalocean Tutorials:- How To Set Up SSH Keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2))
2. The error message points out the pem file are not accessible. So the first steps are to make sure the file is there (or you can copy it to your home directory for testing purposes) and is accessible.