# sftp from Windows-10-v-1803 into WSL Ubuntu-18.04 ssh-server... won't connect

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1803, ubuntu-18.04

Though there are interesting suggestions in:
[How can I SSH into "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10"?](https://superuser.com/questions/1111591/how-can-i-ssh-into-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10?rq=1)
They may be obsolete in Windows-10-v-1803 with the new implementation of WSL.

I Installed WSL and Ubuntu 18.04: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

WSL changed significantly in Windows 10 v1803

Installed openssh-server on wsl ubuntu:  https://gist.github.com/dentechy/de2be62b55cfd234681921d5a8b6be11

Edited sshd_config: sudo nano sshd_config
Added: Port 2222

Restart ssh server:  sudo service ssh --full-restart
Show that server is running:    ps -A | grep sshd
Result:      202 ?     00:00:00 sshd

Open cmd as administrator on Windows 10 then run:  sftp -v -P 2222 [user]@localhost
    Windows 10 now has a built-in ssh client

Result:
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n 7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file of directory
.
.
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4 pat OpenSSH* conpat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:2222 as [user]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 2222

Note: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT s sent, but no response received, is user not authenticated?

Tried running same command from within WSL bash also "Connection closed".  This workflow does connect on a pure Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

Comment: Problem resolved...     I posted this to Microsoft's WSL issues community on github:  therealkenc commented
WSL Ubuntu 18.04 from the Store requires the keys to be created manually. I don't know precisely how this became new behaviour (obviously not deliberately). On 16.04 no one thought much of it. Might have something do with the postinstall script of apt install openssh-server failing, but that's a guess I haven't looked. Anyway:

$ sudo ssh-keygen -A

Comment: Please put this comment as an answer