# how to get local bash shell in Putty

Tags: bash, putty

I want to see if it is possible to access local bash shell via Putty, I can access/use it via MobaXterm or from Linux partition but not from Putty. I am using Putty from Windows.

[image: Putty and local bash shell]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I SSH into "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10"?](https://superuser.com/questions/1111591/how-can-i-ssh-into-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10)

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, this makes sense, i just wasn't able to find it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with Putty.
Putty is a remote terminal client. It just doesn't have the functionality to run a local shell. It connects to a remote system and runs the shell over there.
MobaXTerm can do it, but that is because is a not just a terminal client (like Putty), but also contains a build-in Cygwin shell with a lot of Linux commands. It is this shell that is started by MobaXTerm when you tell it to open a local bash shell.

Opening a terminal window in Linux is an entirely different thing. You just run the shell application (bash or another shell) directly in a local window.
In Windows the equivalent of that would be to run a CMD of POWERSHELL prompt. Or (if you have the WSL (Windows SubSystem for Linux) installed) you could run a Linux terminal (with bash) directly in that.
Last, but not least: You can always run a SSH server in Windows and use Putty to connect to localhost. (But Putty is, technically, still a terminal client in that case. It is just that client and server both happen to run on the same machine.)

Comment: There _are_ forks of PuTTY for Windows which run the shell locally; I believe Cygwin's MinTTY is one of them. (A "pterm" tool even comes by default with PuTTY for Unix/Linux, but I guess it wasn't ported to Windows due to the extra complexity of the Windows console layer.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way like MobaXterm, however it can be achieved by installing [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) and using a middleware between Putty and Cygwin shell like [cygtermd](https://github.com/github/putty/tree/master/contrib/cygtermd).

More details can be found [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/cygwin-terminal-window.html).

It is not so direct to setup, though it only has to setup once.